# How to get data from 2 tables based on search keyword rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.4

I have 2 tables `schools` and `private_schools` and they are not related to each other. What I need to do is to search the data from both tables to populate the results.

Both tables has the attribute `name` from which I need to get results. So when user will write some keyword the data will be searched from both tables.

Here is the query I am trying but it returns errors.

Query:

```
User.includes(:schools, :private_schools).where("schools.name = ? or 
private_schools.name = ?", params[:keyword])
```

I know the `User.` sort of thing is also useless and is also not needed but how we should cope this issue to search keywords from both tables at same time?

Error is:

ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid (wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: schools.name = ? or private_schools.name = ?):

Per comments the code of models are:

Private School:

```
class PrivateSchool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :private_school_specializations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :private_classes
  has_many :invitation_promo_codes
  has_many :popular_schools, as: :resource, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

School:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :students
  has_many :subjects
  has_many :teachers
  has_many :departments
  has_many :student_ids
  has_many :teacher_ids
  has_many :class_rooms
  has_many :popular_schools, as: :resource, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :school
  has_one :student
  has_one :teacher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher
end
```

Comment: Post the code of those three models

Comment: @ShamsulHaque added model code.

Comment: What do you want to get from the two tables? Are the data outputs similar? If not, you will need two separate queries. Otherwise, you can a. map the results into two arrays and join them. So you will have an array of results, not a collection. b. Run raw sql query

Comment: I want to get school names from both tables based on typed search phrase. How I can manage 2 queries in same method? You comments are right and makes sense. :) The thing after otherwise is what I am looking for. So run 2 queries and join them as 1 result set. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have couple of things for you:

1. The `includes` is used to specify relationships to be included in the result set. So you don't have any relationship between `schools` and `private_schools`. So the straight forward you can't query it like this because you can't `join` two tables without having any relation. You can do a separate query for each table `school` and `private_school`.

   ```
   schools = School.where(name: params[:name])
   schools << PrivateSchool.where(name: params[:name])
   schools.flatten!
   ```

You can put both into an array like this and then loop on the view. To just take out the names you can add:

```
   pluck(:name)
```

The includes is different thing. Like for example:

```
User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example')
```

when the `Post` belong to the `User` so what will happen is the `include` will load the `posts` and when you try to fetch the `posts` with `example` name it would not fire any additional query as it has that data already loaded. So this only works when you have a relation between the models.

2. The `school` and `private_school` can be one single model if the attributes of both are same. You can just add an attribute of `is_private` which would be boolean and its value will be `true` in case of private schools. (This will depend on your attributes)

Comment: I would like to go for option 1. is there any example how to run both queries in one method that will look for search keyword? Thanks

Comment: So you will be writing two queries for it in one method and you can add them in one array. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**ERROR REASON** The following query is expecting two params, one to each `?`

```
User.includes(:schools, :private_schools).where("schools.name = ? or 
private_schools.name = ?", params[:keyword])
```

So

```
User.includes(:schools, :private_schools).where("schools.name = ? or 
private_schools.name = ?", params[:keyword], params[:keyword])
```

Or just

```
User.includes(:schools, :private_schools).where("schools.name = :name or 
private_schools.name = :name", name: params[:keyword])
```

**EXPECTING SOMETHING ELSE?**

> I know the User. sort of thing is also useless and is also not needed but how we should cope this issue to search keywords from both tables at same time?

Actually your `User.` query will return a list of users and not a list of schools or private_schools, so if you are not expecting a list of users you might be looking for something else... perhaps a list of schools?

If your `schools` and `private_schools` have the same structure you should take a look into [inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) and use the same table for both models.
For now you could do something like:

```
def my_result
  schools = School.where(name: params[:name]).to_a
  private_schools = PrivateSchool.where(name: params[:name]).to_a
  schools + private_schools # combine both arrays
end
```

Comment: I find `User.` is not necessary as I just wants to query the results from both table without the inclusion of `User` thing. 
`User` is not needed as I have posted the same on above. Can we do that without `User` factor?

Comment: If the tables are not related you would have to do two separate queries... `User.` will return a list of users in those conditions and not a list of schools or private_schools, so not sure what are you looking for

Comment: Yes, I would like to go for separate queries, can we manage that in the same method? your comments make sense to me now. Sorry please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do "complex" queries such as this frequently in your application, I highly recommend you check the "ransack" gem. It makes queries like this a breeze, and your codebase clean.

```
MyModel.search(:private_school_name_or_school_name_cont => params[:q).result
```

ref: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack